# flickering of image in SWT

Tags: image, swt, composite, flicker

I am building an SWT application, I have used a `ScrolledComposite` and a `Composite` inside that. This has a few more buttons and checkboxes . All this is inside a `Composite`.

Now I tried to put this main composite in the tab. It worked fine but the image flickers a lot even if I don't scroll or resize. If I put this main composite inside a shell, its working perfect without any flicker.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` style bit on your [Composite](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html)? That might fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much....That worked.Now there is a new problem.The flickering has stopped. I now added two tabs. One tab has the image and around 15 buttons.When I run the app, the image appears but the buttons dont appear.But if i resize the app, the buttons appear and the app runs really very slow.What might be the reason for this?This was the case even before settin the SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED style bit.

Comment: New problem -> new question please. That way others might also profit from an answer. If the new problem is answered here, no one will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Write `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` in declaration

Example:

```
scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
```