# Flickering while scrolling in SWT

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar

I'm using a SWT `ScrolledComposite` but when I scroll in Windows I get some flickering if I scroll to fast. Can anyone please help me? How can I rectify this?

Comment: Impossible to solve without seeing what you actually do. Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` if you haven't used it already.

Reference: [flickering of image in SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958455/flickering-of-image-in-swt)